# Why is MPI_Bsend() a blocking function?

Tags: mpi, blocking, nonblocking, hpc

As the following definitions show, MPI_Bsend() is a blocking MPI function. But this is against our common understanding of the word 'blocking'. So these questions arise: Are the adjectives 'blocking' and 'nonblocking' helpful in any way in describing MPI functions? If not, why do they exist in the terminology at all?

Definitions of blocking and nonblocking MPI procedures according to the standard:

> An MPI procedure is **nonblocking** if it is **incomplete** and **local**.

> An MPI procedure is **blocking** if it is not **nonblocking**.

Definitions of local and nonlocal MPI procedures:

> An MPI procedure is **nonlocal** if returning may require, during its
> execution, some specific semantically-related MPI procedure to be called on another
> MPI process.

> An MPI procedure is **local** if it is not **nonlocal**.

Definitions of incomplete and completing procedures:

> An MPI procedure is called **incomplete** if it is not a **completing**
> procedure.

> An MPI procedure is called **completing** if return from the procedure indicates that at least one associated operation has finished its completion stage, which implies that the user can rely on the content of the output data buffers and modify the content of input and output data buffers of such operation(s). If a completing procedure is not also a freeing procedure then the user is not permitted to deallocate the data buffers or to modify the array arguments.

So in MPI the concepts of completeness and locality are more fundamental than blocking/nonblocking concept. But why does the latter exist at all?

Comment: can you be more precise about your "common understanding of the word 'blocking'"? Do you expect blocking to mean "wait until the other rank read the data" or something like that?

Comment: @julaine, Yes, intuitively the word 'blocking' sounds like 'nonlocal' as defined above. A nonlocal procedure is not guaranteed to return "soon", so may block the execution of a process.

Comment: well `BSend` (may) return sooner than a `Send` but that is not the point. The point of blocking/non-blocking is that `ISend` imposes certain responsibilities on the caller that `BSend` and `Send` or `SSend` do not impose on the caller. Please see if my answer explains what the concept of 'blocking' does to help with programming.

Comment: non blocking means the sender can overwrite the send buffer as soon as the function returns. It does **not** say anything about the message has been received or even sent (e.g. it does **not** mean the function **might** hang until a matching receive is posted)

Comment: Also note that `Send` may buffer too. `Send` returning does not mean the other rank received the data.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, Quote: "non blocking means the sender can overwrite the send buffer as soon as the function returns." This is the definition of "completing procedure" (the last definition in the post).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, My own surmise is that blocking and nonblocking are old concepts in MPI, and that recently the designers have found the concepts of completeness and locality more accurate/useful, but since the terms blocking and nonblocking have become so accepted by the users, the designers have not removed them from the standard.

Comment: The draft of the MPI standard was released in the previous century, so yes, do not assume concepts are always what you think/hope they should be (and this is not limited to MPI)

Answer (score 1):

The usefulness of the blocking/nonblocking concept is explained in the [standard (4.1, pdf)](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-4.1/mpi41-report.pdf) as an "advice to users" on page 15:

> Advice to users. Note that for operation-related MPI procedures, in most cases
> incomplete procedures are local and completing procedures are nonlocal. Exceptions
> are noted where such procedures are defined

So the concepts exist because many functions can be described as blocking, it is essentially a shorthand.

---

Now why is `BSend` considered blocking?

It is *complete* because the calling rank may do whatever it wants with the buffer that it passed to the function after the function completes. Modifying it is legal.
It is *local* because no other operation is required to complete the operation.

Contrast this with `ISend`, where the function returns quickly, but the send-buffer may not be used or freed yet, and the status needs to be awaited.

---

So is the concept useful? I would say their usefulness is **describing programmer responsibilities**:

local/non-local describes the behaviour of functions you need to consider if you are looking to avoid deadlocks.

complete/incomplete describes the behaviour of functions you need to consider to avoid memory-bugs.

Since you need to consider both for a correct program, it is important to know where your functions are. "Blocking" is an easy mnemonic for the most common communications like `Send` or `BCast`. Common in the sense that they appear first historically and in tutorials. If you know that a function is non-blocking you know it deviates from this model.

Comment: @apadana blocking means both nonlocal and complete. These usually go together but not always.

Comment: Please see my last comment to Gilles Gouaillardet below the post.

Comment: @apadana you have a point - ability to use the buffer is only related to being 'complete', so that would be the correct term when talking about potential memory errors. Meanwhile local/nonlocal is the important distinction to make when talking about potential deadlocks. I like your theory that blocking/non-blocking is an older concept that later got split into two concepts but the word survived. I don't have the historical knowledge to tell if it's true.

Comment: @apadana I have made some edits to disentangle completeness and locality. Thank you for this question, I got better at MPI because of it.